# Angular Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, api

I have the code working perfectly, but no console log is giving these errors. It is not possible to read `results` from the property of indefinite.
Could someone tell me what it is?
What am I doing wrong?
This application is making a request to a TMDB api

```js
MODEL ANGULAR

export interface Movies {
  results: (ResultsEntity)[];
  page: number;
  total_results: number;
  dates: Dates;
  total_pages: number;
}

export interface ResultsEntity {
  popularity: number;
  vote_count: number;
  video: boolean;
  poster_path: string;
  id: number;
  adult: boolean;
  backdrop_path: string;
  original_language: string;
  original_title: string;
  genre_ids?: (number)[] | null;
  title: string;
  vote_average: number;
  overview: string;
  release_date: string;
}
export interface Dates {
  maximum: string;
  minimum: string;
}
```

```html
method list angular 

<div class="img carousel-cell" *ngFor="let m of movies.results">  
            <img routerLink="edit/{{m.id}}" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200{{ m?.poster_path }}" alt="{{ m.title }}"/>
          </div>
          
          
          
Service Angular

  subs: Subscription[] = []
  latest!: Movies;
  nowPlaying!: Movies;
  comedy!: Movies;
  horror!: Movies;
  animation!: Movies;
  documentary!: Movies;
  originals!: Movies;
  

  constructor(public movies: ServiceApiService ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subs.push(this.movies.getNowPlayingMovie().subscribe(res => this.nowPlaying  =res));
    this.subs.push(this.movies.getComedy().subscribe(res => this.comedy  =res));
    this.subs.push(this.movies.getHorror().subscribe(res => this.horror  =res));
    this.subs.push(this.movies.getAnimation().subscribe(res => this.animation  =res));
    this.subs.push(this.movies.getDocumentary().subscribe(res => this.documentary  =res));
    this.subs.push(this.movies.getOriginals().subscribe(res => this.originals  =res));
    
  }
```

Comment: Hmmm, your `movies` is `ServiceApiService`?! Maybe you can create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that there are movies, test...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="movies && movies.results.length > 0">
    <div class="img carousel-cell" *ngFor="let m of movies.results">
        <img routerLink="edit/{{m.id}}" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200{{ m?.poster_path }}" alt="{{ m.title }}"/>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```